# SlideToggle triggered by onScroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle, onscroll

I'm getting stuck on two things here that I'd appreciate the help with.

**Background:**

The banner displays a photo and some information. However this is not supposed to be everpresent. The banner has to, but not all the information. So there is an option to collapse it and expand it with an icon (like an accordion).

**Problems**

1. Because the panel has to be fixed, I had to position relative the content below it. Problem is, when I collapse it, the content is still respecting the position given. I'd like that content to respect the distance between each other instead so that if there is 20px between them, that would still be true on a collapsed view. (I tried margin and top) but no cigar.
2. And my main issue which I have no idea how to get it done is, I'd like the banner to collapse automatically on scroll. I know there is a scroll function out there, I just never used it before.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="header navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" data-current-theme="navbar-inverse">
    <p>menu &amp; logo</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="banner clearfix">
            <div class="collapser">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-fw collapse-icon"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="banner-info clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <div class="circle-container">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTGjucaoN3fabOcumnr7RKTB3ICTJFLuLClnpiQUIR9oW4a11wb" alt="offender-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <span>Floyd "Money" Mayweather</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Some Label</label>
                            <span>Something Here</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Offender ID#</label>
                            <span>123569863</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Longer Label Example</label>
                            <span>Something Here with an ellipsis</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Institution</label>
                            <span>Graterford</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Some Link</label>
                            <a href="#"><span>Something Here</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Institution</label>
                            <span>Graterford</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Some Link</label>
                            <span href="#"><p>Something Here</p></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container martop65">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et meis definitiones cum, audire iisque alterum no ius. Semper luptatum democritum has no, at sea audire inermis suscipiantur. Ei regione adipiscing ius. An est nonumy habemus, movet probatus recusabo eu eum. Hinc offendit te est, at his falli euripidis.
    <br><br>
    Pertinax scribentur ullamcorper in nec, sit dolor fastidii ei. Cetero pericula iudicabit no est, tale elitr ad has, eos sumo harum interesset eu. His ne fierent appareat. Vel paulo fierent eleifend id. Pri ut conceptam repudiandae theophrastus, enim periculis ius ex, te est numquam inimicus.
    <br><br>

    Congue deleniti deseruisse te eos, usu no brute laoreet. Nisl lorem zril eu qui. Vix tempor inimicus an, partem minimum cotidieque mel eu. Aperiam discere an mea, ea graecis scribentur mel, minim ludus saperet no vix. Has at sint sanctus. Eu docendi hendrerit liberavisse mel, ut eum viris voluptaria, eum error voluptua principes ex.
    <br><br>                
    Vis te accumsan lucilius platonem. Possit prodesset eum in. No duo agam nullam detracto. At homero scaevola electram vel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    .navbar {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #30373e;
        font-size: 14px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.025);
        box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.025);
        z-index: 1040;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        height: 55px;
        text-align:center;
        color:#ccc;
    }

    .banner {
        border: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -ms-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        background: #101113;
        padding: 20px;
        display: block;
        top: 55px;
        border-radius:0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .banner .collapser {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        color: #bbb;
    }

    .banner .circle-container {
        position: relative;
        left: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        -ms-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 3px solid #bbb;
    }

    .banner .banner-info label {
        color: rgba(248,151,29,0.77);
    }

    .banner .banner-info span {
        display: block;
        color: #bbb;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 85%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

.martop65 {
   /* margin-top: 240px;*/
    position:relative;
    top:240px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.collapser').click(function() {
    $collapser = $(this);
    $banner = $collapser.parent().find('.banner-info .circle-container').add($collapser.parent().find(".col-md-10 > .col-md-3 > .form-group:nth-of-type(2)"));

    $banner.slideToggle(500, function() {
        $collapser.find('.collapse-icon').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });
});
```

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/WrXYWE)

Thanks!

Comment: not 100% clear about layout expected results but for scroll `$(window).on('scroll', function(){ })`

Comment: I'll mess with that and see how far I can get but on regards to layout,  if you open the codepen, it's easy to see.  Thanks for the tip tho